# using a variable in another function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to use the new declared variable in a other function

I tried making it global but i have to declare it in the slider function

```
var rsv = 0

@IBAction func rateSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    rsv = Int(sender.value)
    hhh.text = String(rsv)
    //if rsv < 33{
    //rating.text = "low"
    //}
    //if rsv > 33 && rsv < 66{
     //   rating.text = "test"
    //}
    //if rsv > 66{
     //   rating.text = "High"
    //}
    //i want the above to only be outputted when the submitBTN is clicked        
}

@IBAction func submitBTN(_ sender: UIButton) {
    nameOutput.text = nameInput.text
    locationOutput.text = locationInput.text
    rating.text = String(rsv)
}
```

rsv is outputted correctly in the slider function but is still outputted as 0 as I do not know how to get the declared version of it in the slider to go in the submitBTN function. rsv shouldn't be 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed with the logic. You should put the code where you want it to execute. So if *you want some codes to **only** be outputted **when the submitBTN is clicked*** you should put that in to `submitBTN` function.

```
@IBAction func rateSlider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    rsv = Int(sender.value)
    hhh.text = String(rsv)    
}

@IBAction func submitBTN(_ sender: UIButton) {
    nameOutput.text = nameInput.text
    locationOutput.text = locationInput.text

    if rsv < 33{
       rating.text = "low"
    } else if rsv > 33 && rsv < 66{
       rating.text = "test"
    } else if rsv > 66{
       rating.text = "High"
    }
}
```